# Why I get error when pass range defined as string into range

Tags: excel, vba, string, range

Here is my simple code

```
Sub SavePrices()
'
' SavePrices saves spot prices from Sheet 'Spot' into Sheet 'saved prices'
'
Dim MyRangeS As String
MyRangeS = Sheets("saved prices").Range("I1").Value

Sheets("saved prices").Range(MyRangeS).Value = Sheets("Spot").Range("A2:C112").Value

End Sub
```

In cell I1 there is a VLOOKUP formula which gives a result A2:C113. When I run the code it gives 1004 Error. If I put A2:C113 i/o MyRangeS it works. While debugging MyRangeS equals to "A2:C113".

Have no idea what it can be.

Please advise.

P.S. The code is written in Module.

Comment: What does `Debug.print len(myranges)` output?

Comment: You say your debugging yields "A2:C113". If it returns with the quotes, you might want to get rid of those. As a test, you could add `MyRangeS = Replace(MyRangeS, Chr(34), vbNullString)` before using it as a range, to see if it helps.

Comment: the ranges need to be equal in size if you want to equal the ranges., you can't have 1 cell value is equal to a bunch of cell values.

Comment: Christofer, the quotes are required there, so that was fine. The issue was that when I defined a range i.g. (="A"&"2"&":C"&"113") I type in cyrillic, which made the code to look correct.

Comment: Davesexcel, the range for saving data one raw longe, that is fine, I left it just in case. It works.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake, the string which I passed to Range was "A2:C112", but letters were typed with Ukrainian language. So it looked totally the same but didn't work.